# git submodule update --checkout using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've got a git project with lots of submodules, and for one of those submodules there's `update = none` set in `.gitmodules`, so that it would not be cloned (but rather skipped) during `git submodule update`. This was made for convenience, so that smaller submodules would be downloaded all together with a single command, but the huge and heavy one would not (still with an option to download it manually if needed)

And the only way to get it downloaded I know of is specifying `--checkout` flag for the `git submodule update` command, but this is something that can be done from command line. Is there a way to do such a thing using TortoiseGit GUI? I tried 'force' 'remote tracking branch', etc., but got `Skipping submodule` message all the way.

Comment: Please fire an issue here: https://tortoisegit.org/issues